# G751JY after 14.04 LTS installation stuck at booting (purple screen)

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation, asus, nomodeset

I'm not really experienced with Ubuntu and currently stuck with the installation of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my new Asus G751JY which came with Win8 preinstalled.

After deleting all pre-made partitions with the live-CD (incl. Win8), I installed Ubuntu (had to use the  `nomodeset` parameter). I'm using the standard partitions created by Ubuntu itself, the only difference is that it's installed on `/dev/sdb` since that one is the SSD. ( `/dev/sda` is 1TB, partitioned ext4 by myself )

**Unfortunately directly after rebooting (maybe 2 seconds) the laptop get's stuck at a simple purple background screen that I read about here sometimes already. It doesn't respond to any keystrokes except ctrl+alt+delete for reboot.**

There is only a very short moment between the initialization of the reboot and the purple screen, but after some attempts I managed to get into grub by hitting shift like a maniac:
- *replacing `quiet splash` or `$linux_gfx_mode` with `nomodeset` doesn't seem to change anything, it's still stuck*
- *before that I tried to edit `nomodeset` into the grub file and also created the file again via the live-CD, without any results* 
- *"Fast Boot" and "Launch CSM" is disabled in the BIOS*
- *however only for the optical drive the BIOS says that the boot option is "UEFI: long drivename", the other options are "ubuntu (PO: Samsung ...)"*

System specs:
Intel HM87 (Lynx Point) Mainboard
Intel i7-4720HQ (4x2,6Ghz)
Geforce GTX 980M (4GB VRAM)
32GB RAM (4x8GB)

I would suspect that this has to do with the graphics driver not loading correctly, since I had to use `nomodeset` for the installation or maybe with the fact that Ubuntu is installed on /dev/sdb and somehow fails to load? But those are just my amateur thoughts ...

I really appreciate any help on this, since it prevents me from booting and using the laptop without the live-CD.

Greetings
Christopher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since I am new to Linux I finally "fixed" this after many hours of reading through forum posts and trying many different approaches by simply switching to 15.04 Vivid Vervet instead of 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to try:
ctrl+alt+f2 login with username and pass.
now type
 `sudo service lightdm restart`
let me know if this helps otherwise we can try to remove lightdm and install gdm

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately I don't get to the point where I can use this (or I'm using it at the wrong point), anyway it doesn't work at the empty purple screen.

Comment: Maybe I can assist you further if you could post your computers specs.